# Convert .zip into tar.gz inside dockerfile[solve]

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I got dockerfile that download .zip folder, because the docker container doesn't have *apt-get*. I cannot *unzip* it, but it seems that .tar.gz convert is embendded in dockerfile.

How do i convert .zip into .tar.gz in dockerfile?

is there any alternative? gunzip doesn't work either.

```
somezipfile.zip has more than one entry -- unchanged
```

The Part of Dockerfile

```
RUN curl -LJO http://somelink.com/verynew_python.zip

RUN gunzip -S .zip verynew_python.zip
ADD verynew_python.tar.gz /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x  /usr/bin/verynew_python/bin/python3.7
```

sorry i cannot post all dockerfile, but this is the part that important. i want to make python3.7 as main python.. there is no wget either.

Comment: hard to tell what are you trying to do. Why not add apt-get / unzip etc... to the docker, if it's needed?

Comment: company security policy, the ubuntu doesn't have apt-get and can't get one. so i try to find alternative..

Comment: Please post your entire Dockerfile and what you want to do.

Comment: if you have `dpkg` available you could install from [.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/unzip). Building from source might be painful without apt.

Comment: yes, I tried that. it quite pain just to install one package just based on command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install packages in your docker containers - if you are free to choose something like this works:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache unzip

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY testfile.zip .
RUN unzip testfile.zip
RUN rm testfile.zip
RUN tar czvf testfile.tgz *
```

This results in:

```
$ docker run -ti x sh
/tmp # ls
testfile      testfile.tgz
/tmp #
```

This is quite inelegant but works. If your base image is from docker hub you can lookup if it is build on a distro and if yes which one it was and choose the "right" package manager for it - most often `apk`, `yum` or `apt`.

Keep in mind that - to keep images small - package caches are often not available and you need to fetch them like `apt update` or must use a non caching method like above.

Answer (score -2):

Does your docker container have **wget** ? You could have downloaded the **unzip** then and run it!

Comment: unfortunately no, only curl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).